# How can I Marshal.IntPtrToStruct MYSQL_FIELD?

Tags: c#, c++, mysql, marshalling

I try to make interface for mysqld.dll (embeded MySQL). I could make core code and share it on https://github.com/mkysoft/eMySQL
I have problem about converting MYSQL_FIELD struct to C# struct which are returning from MySQL query. I try this with below code.

```
IntPtr result = mysql_store_result(_MySQL);
IntPtr fields = mysql_fetch_fields(result)
var Fields = (IntPtr[])MarshalArray(typeof(IntPtr), fields, (int)fieldCount);
var obj = (MySQLH.MYSQL_FIELD)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Fields[0], typeof(MySQLH.MYSQL_FIELD))
```

But I am getting access validation error or irrelevant values. I playing with c# struct type with MySQL MYSQL_FIELD struct type from MySQL source code. Any hint is acceptable. The project and dll are x64.

Original MYSQL_FIELD C++ structure type (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/include/mysql.h):

```
typedef struct st_mysql_field {
  char *name;                 /* Name of column */
  char *org_name;             /* Original column name, if an alias */
  char *table;                /* Table of column if column was a field */
  char *org_table;            /* Org table name, if table was an alias */
  char *db;                   /* Database for table */
  char *catalog;          /* Catalog for table */
  char *def;                  /* Default value (set by mysql_list_fields) */
  unsigned long length;       /* Width of column (create length) */
  unsigned long max_length;   /* Max width for selected set */
  unsigned int name_length;
  unsigned int org_name_length;
  unsigned int table_length;
  unsigned int org_table_length;
  unsigned int db_length;
  unsigned int catalog_length;
  unsigned int def_length;
  unsigned int flags;         /* Div flags */
  unsigned int decimals;      /* Number of decimals in field */
  unsigned int charsetnr;     /* Character set */
  enum enum_field_types type; /* Type of field. See mysql_com.h for types */
  void *extension;
} MYSQL_FIELD;
```

I got some way:
I change struct data types than I can get %90 of structure values. But I can't ensure result. May be other field types failed. I test some of them.
New MYSQL_FIELD structure like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MYSQL_FIELD
{
    string name;                 /* Name of column */
    string org_name;             /* Original column name, if an alias */
    string table;                /* Table of column if column was a field */
    string org_table;            /* Org table name, if table was an alias */
    string db;                   /* Database for table */
    string catalog;              /* Catalog for table */
    string def;                  /* Default value (set by mysql_list_fields) */
    uint length;                 /* Width of column (create length) */
    uint max_length;             /* Max width for selected set */
    uint name_length;
    uint org_name_length;
    uint table_length;
    uint org_table_length;
    uint db_length;
    uint catalog_length;
    uint def_length;
    uint flags;                  /* Div flags */
    uint decimals;               /* Number of decimals in field */
    enum_charset_types charset;  /* Character set */
    //uint charsetnr;            /* Character set */
    enum_field_types type;       /* Type of field. See mysql_com.h for types */
    IntPtr extension;
}
```

Comment: I implemented mysql_fetch_field method. It can be converted but values OK, other bad.
var field = mysql_fetch_field(result);
var obj = (MySQLH.MYSQL_FIELD)Marshal.PtrToStructure(field, typeof(MySQLH.MYSQL_FIELD));

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the original definition of the MySQL_FIELD struct from the C++ code as well?